# How can I system test Java desktop applications?

Tags: java, testing, functional-testing

There are lots of tools to perform end-to-end testing of web-based applications (for example, Selenium). Is there something similar to test a desktop Java application that runs directly on the user's computer?

Comment: Which toolkit do you use? AWT? Swing? SWT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WindowTester](https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/wintester/) from Google.

> WindowTester Pro (also known as just WindowTester) eliminates the need
>   to manually create test cases to test GUIs by automating the process
>   of GUI testing.

Answer (score 1):

[Eclipse Jubula](http://eclipse.org/jubula/documentation.php) is what you are looking for.